# temporarily disabling access to a schema in Oracle : lock account vs revoke grant

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a usecase where I need to block access to all objects in a schema **temporarily** while I perform some massive changes. I plan to perform the changes as the schema owner. Once I am done I want to enable access back. I am currently exploring two options and would like to know your thoughts as to which one works better :

1. Lock all accounts that go against the database objects in target schema.
2. Revoke grants on the database objects and hence preventing external users from using it.

Is there are better way? I want the process to be as smooth as possible and insure that no one is able to get to the target schema while the change is going on

Comment: Is this change DDL or object compilations?  As in, is the real issue that you are trying to prevent is you are concerned with active sessions blocking your changes?  Is this correct?

Comment: Its DDL as well DML changes. And yes we want to block users to prevent them from using stale data while we are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger. This trigger works for everybody except the user with dba role.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon_audit_trigger
   AFTER LOGON
   ON DATABASE
DECLARE
BEGIN
     raise_application_error (-20001, 'You cannot login.');
END;
```

If you want to know who and where is trying to login. You can get thses information from SYS_CONTEXT.

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') 
   FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thanks. But my real question is which approach is better and why

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to quiesce the database.  The downsides to locking out users or revoking permissions is that users will receive errors (you don't have access or you can't login, etc...).  Quiesceing the database means that active sessions will finish their work, but then will hang until the database is un-quiesced.  Then, you perform your modifications and will be guaranteed that nothing can block your exclusive access to the objects you are updating.  After your update (or even during your update after you have the lock on the object in question), unquiesce the database.

Of course, the downside to this approach is that this is across the entire database instead of to just one schema.  The advantage to this is that your users won't experience any error messages, and if you turn your DML into DDL (as described below) to greatly speed up the downtime window, the majority of your users shouldn't experience much more than a few seconds of inactivity.

There is a good write up on quiesceing the database at [Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2943).  You would have to get your DBA's involved to both quiesce the database and to put your changes live as only system or sys can perform this operation.

For DML, you could consider creating a new table with the data that you want before the downtime window starts.  Then when the downtime window starts, rename the old table, rename the new table as the old table, recreate the permissions, for a much faster downtime window (since this effectively turns a DML update into DDL).  Tom Kyte has a discussion of this approach [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330).

Also, it goes without saying that proper testing in a testing environment of the above procedures should be done, which will iron out any gotchas in this process and give you a pretty good idea of how long the system will need to be quiesced for.